# how to add new SKScene With in SKScene in SpritKit Swift

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I have to add next SKScene in SpritKit in swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
    {
        var objgamescen = GameScene()

        //objgamescen.initWithSize(self.size, playerWon: true)
        self.view .presentScene(objgamescen)
    }
```

Then GameScene is Blanked  and Self.frame is (0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)

Comment: Read the "Transitioning Between Two Scenes" section here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Transitions/Transitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH8-SW2

Comment: Are you starting the same scene over again?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Scene Added in SKScene By This:

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        var scene: HomeScene!
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 568 {
                scene = HomeScene(size: CGSizeMake(480, 320))
            }else {
                scene = HomeScene(size: CGSizeMake(568, 320))
            }
        }else {
            scene = HomeScene(size: CGSizeMake(1024, 768))
        }

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to restart the scene, you can do that by creating a function like this

```
func goToGameScene(){
let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size) // create your new scene
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0) // create type of transition (you can check in documentation for more transtions)
gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fill
self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Then you just call it where you want it to take place

```
goToGameScene()
```